# PHP handling multiple carts in the sesison

Tags: php, e-commerce

what is the best way to maintain the session for multiple carts independently in php? Do we have to save the session for each cart with different name ?
or do we have to use some unique session id to identify the cart and keeping the session name for each cart same ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create array of carts in one session variable and store multiple cart data in it.